always force to update an Entity
The problem that I found is that JPA behavior is that always has to have a change in an entity to trigger a PreUpdate with do a save().
What I want is a way to find a entity in the db and them say update the date using PreUpdate.
My code looks like this:
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table")
public class TableEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "uuid2"
    )
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "Something")
    private String something;

    @Column(name = "Fecha")
    private LocalDateTime fecha;

    @PreUpdate
    private void update() {
        setFecha(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}

Repository is blank repository without any custom method.
The service that I have has an autowired of the repository.
Then I have a method like this:
    @Transactional
    public InformationDTO save(String id) {

        TableEntity entity = capRepository.findById(id);

        entity.setSomething("mock");

        repo.save(entity);

        [...]
        return new InformationDTO();
    }

If I do this, the PreUpdate will trigger and happy days, but if instead of that, I do this method,
    @Transactional
    public InformationDTO save(String id) {

        TableEntity entity = capRepository.findById(id);

        repo.save(entity);

        [...]
        return new InformationDTO();
    }

this won't trigger the PreUpdate.
Is there any way to trigger the PreUpdate without any modification of the entity?

You can just call update yourself.

I was trying to do the PreUpdate 100% invisible to the developer, but looks like they will need to call update(). Thanks for your help :)

You can do it on load of entity:)
